# Where is "classes" folder in newly created pod project (from 'pod lib create')

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to create a new pod that follows the 'standard' template.  I use 'pod lib create' to create an empty project/workspace.  When I open the Xcode workspace, I don't see any place in the 'development pods' folder in which to place my code.  I was expecting a "classes" directory or similar.

this is what I am seeing

[Xcode structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5lmq.png)

I tried creating class files as peers to "ReplaceMe.swift" but they seem to disappear from Xcode.  I tried creating a "classes" directory (which will need sub-directories) and get an error from Xcode.

Expecting to see a classes folder where I can put my code + ability to create subdirectories under it to properly organize it.  I have seen examples of pods that start out this way that have the proper set of folders in Xcode, so perhaps this is something that used to work in the past.

I have created other pods that work, but would like to follow the standard template for all of the obvious reasons. thanks!

Comment: ok, I was able to get a reasonable Xcode structure together. I then committed everything to repo, updated tags to reflect latest commit.  upon a subsequent 'pod install', the Xcode structure reverted to what it was before I changed anything. my changes were lost.  seems like something is creating the Xcode struct during the install? I have other pods that I created without using this template and they don't have these issues.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on `ReplaceMe.swift` and select "Show in Finder…".

That will get you to the right folder. I have found it is better to drag the files into the classes folder and then add them to Xcode, otherwise them seem to end up in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2):

Found the cause of the issue. It was due to unexpected behavior of the "source_files" directive when creating the DevelopmentPods folder.

In some circumstances, it does not add the next level (e.g. "Classes") folder to the project, but merges all of its contents with the next higher level directory. In this case, while all of the classes are brought in, it is impossible to create new classes with Xcode in the DevelopmentPod classes directory.

To prevent this, if I create one "dummy" source file as a sibling to the Classes directory (not within the classes directory), it all works out.  The generated Xcode structure mimics the file directory structure, I can create new files and they show up in expected directories, etc.  The classes folder, all files within and all sub-folders show up.